Checking Positive-Definiteness of Hessian in Matrix Calculus
Let $X$ be a $2 \times N$ matrix and $\mathbf{v}$ an $N \times 1$ column vector. I am considering the following function of a matrix input:
$$ f(X) = \|X \mathbf{v} \|_2.$$
My goal is to compute the Hessian of $f$ and check whether it is positive-definite.
I can use the Matrix Cookbook to compute that the gradient is
$$\nabla_X f =  \frac{1}{\|X \mathbf{v}\|_2} X \cdot \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}^\top.$$
As I am new to matrix calculus, I am not sure how to proceed. How does the usual procedure work when $f$ is a function of a matrix?

The Hessian will be a $2N\times 2N$ matrix, so it's probably better to represent it in block form, i.e. derive with respect to the two columns of $X$

Could you say more?

use $z=vec(X)$ as a variable, that is a vector formed by joining the two rows of $X$. Now derive with respect to $z$ as you would do normally

If I replace $z$ with the vectorized matrix $X$, then what happens to the matrix multiplication between $X$ and $\mathbf{v}$ in the definition of $f$? After this procedure, should I think of $f$ just as a function of the one variable $z$?

$z = [x_1,, x_2]$ where $x_1, x_2$ are the rows of $X$. Then $|Xv| = | [x_1v, , x_2v  ]  |$

@Exodd but then how would I be able to differentiate with rest to $z$?

@TedBlack what is that expression on the left-hand side? I’ve never seen that notation before. Or how you get this expression.
